# How do I move sprite character

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've done the sprite animations ( walking, standing, attack ) now I'm having problem figuring out how to make the character move and attack when I press certain buttons.

This is the script that I tried.

```
using System.Collections;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour {

    Rigidbody2D rbody;
    Animator anim;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        rbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        Vector2 movement_vector = new Vector2(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"), Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical"));

        if (movement_vector != Vector2.zero)   {

            anim.SetBool("iswalking", true);
            anim.SetFloat("Input_x"), movement_vector.x);
            anim.SetFloat("Input_y"), movement_vector.y);
        }
        else {
            anim.SetBool( "iswalking", false);
        }

        rbody.MovePosition(rbody.position + movement_vector * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FNp_y_Ickhs

Comment: You modify the `transform` property of your gameObject not the rigidbody itselt. Go to Unity website, and in their tutorial section they have a few examples of 2D games.